# Haar-Cascade - haar.cpp

Tags: c, opencv, classification, face-detection, haar-classifier

I am having trouble understanding what some of the members of the classes below mean. I  am not sure what the **weight** in *CvHidHaarFeature* means, what the **threshold**, **left** and **right** values mean in  *CvHidHaarTreeNode*. I am also having trouble understanding what the **count** means and what the **alpha** means in *CvHidHaarClassifier*. Any insight at all would be very helpful :).

```
   typedef struct CvHidHaarFeature
  {
      struct
      {
          sumtype *p0, *p1, *p2, *p3;
          float weight;
      }
      rect[CV_HAAR_FEATURE_MAX];
  } CvHidHaarFeature;
  
  
  typedef struct CvHidHaarTreeNode
  {
      CvHidHaarFeature feature;
      float threshold;
      int left;
      int right;
  } CvHidHaarTreeNode;
  
  
  typedef struct CvHidHaarClassifier
  {
      int count;
      CvHidHaarTreeNode* node;
      float* alpha;
 } CvHidHaarClassifier;
 
 
 typedef struct CvHidHaarStageClassifier
 {
     int  count;
     float threshold;
     CvHidHaarClassifier* classifier;
     int two_rects;
 
     struct CvHidHaarStageClassifier* next;
     struct CvHidHaarStageClassifier* child;
     struct CvHidHaarStageClassifier* parent;
 } CvHidHaarStageClassifier;
 
 
 typedef struct CvHidHaarClassifierCascade
 {
     int  count;
     int  isStumpBased;
     int  has_tilted_features;
     int  is_tree;
     double inv_window_area;
     CvMat sum, sqsum, tilted;
     CvHidHaarStageClassifier* stage_classifier;
     sqsumtype *pq0, *pq1, *pq2, *pq3;
     sumtype *p0, *p1, *p2, *p3;
 
     void** ipp_stages;
 } CvHidHaarClassifierCascade;
```

Comment: is that the ancient OpenCV v1.x API? that hasn't been supported for years. just saying. it's unlikely that you'll get answers to this. you'll have to dig up the old code and browse it.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, do you know where the newer open-cv is? Because I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: huh? opencv.org is the starting point. docs.opencv.org for docs, github.com/opencv/opencv for the source.

Comment: I checked the sites that you suggested and they don't have the relevant documentation for the haar.cpp above. Do you know where I could find it?

Comment: docs for v1.x are hard to find. if you have source code for opencv v1.x, you have docs too. you *may* be able to find v1 API docs in v2.x documentation. -- you need to realize that this is now *code archaeology*. there are no simple answers. you may have to *guess* what the code does, and throw the old parts away entirely.

Comment: All right, thanks Christoph :)